# how does the caching process work in ASE 15.0.3

Tags: sql, caching, database-performance, sap-ase

I am monitoring a Sybase server (ASE 15.0.3) for it's performance. One of the things it monitors is the cached data. but I want to understand how the caching process really works in ASE 15.0.3. Can one instance of ASE 15.0.3 cache statements running in another instance or is the caching limited to it's own instance. And what are the tables used in the caching process in both the case of self caching and cross caching
NOTE: by performance I mean Full set of performance tuning as supported by ASE 15.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ASE uses the 'default data cache' for data cache and 'procedure cache' to cache 'SP query plans'. As from ASE15.x (not in compatibility mode), 'statement cache' can be used for optimization to cache query plans of SQL statement that are re-used a lot.

I use sp_sysmon to collect server-wide performance measures and read the following doc to optimize my data cache:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20020.1502/html/basics/X56939.htm

The very useful MDA tables are generating too much overhead in my system so I try to only use temporary to collect performance measure.
Hope this helps.